# Setting geometry to origin doesn't work

Tags: python, scripting, collada

So I'm trying to write a script that would take the name of each object in the scene and import the Collada file having the exact same name as the object in the scene. After import I want to set all objects' origin to geometry (i.e., for those objects that already were in the scene and for all the objects imported from Collada files).

```
import bpy
import os 


folder = 'E:\\path'

# importing .dae files and renaming them
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    name = ob.name
    path = os.path.join(folder, name[10:] + '.dae')
    bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=path)
    path = ''
    
    # renaming objects
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        obj.name = name
        obj.data.name = name

# setting the geometry to origin for all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
```

The main issue is that the origin is not set for objects if I'm using this script. If I put the last two lines before the main for-loop then the origin of the objects that were already in the scene is changed. If I use the last two lines of the script listed below as a separate script, then the origin of the all objects is set to geometry as it should.

I assume it might be related to how Blender selects objects, but not sure. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you need to do `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`?

Comment: I tried adding this line before the last 2 lines in my script and it didn't work. The object's origin is still not set to geometry.

Comment: Try with `for ob in bpy.data.objects[:]:`. You're iterating over the list of objects but you keep adding objects to it, so I'm not surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: Gorgious is right, though then the program should hang (infinite loop), which you should inevitably notice (the interface would freeze)

Comment: It worked, thanks. So the problem was that the initial list of objects was not updated at each loop, right? Not sure I understand exactly

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady it actually didn't freeze (at least there wasn't any change for the whole running time since I import ca. 1200 objects)